# New users must login through <node>.salesforce.com instead of test.salesforce.com?

Tags: user, login-errors, login

Has anyone recognized this problem lately where a user has to login through their specific instance's node (cs1,cs2, ...), rather than through test.salesforce.com?

Is it just because these users are so new it hasn't propagated yet?

Comment: I got exactly the same issue today - seems that if affects only a few orgs / useres. Any insight on this would be great. Did you get this solved this? Simply wait for a while until it propagates?

Comment: Just waiting for now @UweHeim

Comment: Correction: it affects ALL orgs and ALL users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue still unfixed but in review and we are not alone (it affects at least 59 others).

If you haven't already you should state there that it affects you, too.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4hLAAS

> **Summary**
>
> After a sandbox has been activated, it may take up to 5 hours
>   for login attempts via the test.salesforce.com login portal to be
>   successful.
>
> This is due to a delay in the replication of the user from the new
>   sandbox environment to the redirection pointer on the test login
>   server.
>
> In some scenarios, the replication delay seems to also occur when
>   creating new users in a sandbox environment.
>
> **Repro**
>
> After your sandbox has been refreshed, attempt to log into the
>   environment from Test.salesforce.com. After several hours, the login
>   attempts will be successful once the replication has completed.
>
> **Workaround**
>
> The current workaround is to log into the application
>   directly from the server in which this sandbox environment is hosted.
>   This will bypass the test login server completely.
>
> To login directly to the server, access the login page for the server
>   itself.
>
> For example, if you organization resides on the cs5 environment you
>   would log in via https://cs5.salesforce.com.
>
> If you are using My Domains and not sure which server you should be
>   accessing, please define the domain for the environment into the field
>   on this page.